# Move Production MetaData to Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, appexchange, scratch-org, 2gp

I am taking my first attempt at walking through 2GP. I have a production org (with no data) that I want to package and put on the AppExchange. I have followed these instructions: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_workflow.htm and am at step 3 where I created a scratch org. The org is empty though. I want to pull everything from my production org and put it into my scratch org. My initial thought was to copy over the XML from the manifest but in VSCode is is not very descriptive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <status>Inactive</status>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

I know there are some apps on the AppExhange that help with this but is there a free way of copying everything over? I read something about Shape orgs but they seem to not carry everything over. Am I on the right track with copying over the manifest to the scratch org?

Answer (score 1):

[Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/developer-experience) is everything you need to accomplish your task.

A very quick way to do this is to create a [Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading_unmanaged.htm) in the Production Org, add everything you want to use to it, then use the -n option to pull everything from that package.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -u prod-login-alias -n "My Package"
```

Of course, if you already have the package.xml the way you want, that's also acceptable:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -u prod-login-alias -x "package.xml"
```

Once retrieved, you can then push to your scratch org:

```
sfdx force:source:push -u scratch-org-alias
```

Note that the Scratch Org comes without any default settings, such as Person Accounts. If you need extra features, set them in your `scratch-org-definition.json` file (whatever that's called).

Available options are found in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) (this is split in several pages, use the menu to find all options). If you're missing an option, when you try to push, you'll get dependency errors; you can review the documentation to find which features you need to enable to resolve this.